# Kubernetes, Fluentd: Match `stdout` logs

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, fluentd

I have a Fluentd running as `DaemonSet` in my Kubernetes cluster. Multiple applications are deployed in the form of microservices on the cluster spanned across namespaces by the same name as microservice name.

A microservice (By the name `payments`) outputs logs to `stdout`. I want to parse that microservice logs and put to some destination in Fluentd. The problem is that I want that specific microservice `payments` logs only. If I use:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  ....
</source>
```

It will scan all pods that output logs to `stdout` I want to filter that specific microservice logs. Is there a way we can do this in Fluentd? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

each Pod creates a log file in containers directory at `/var/lib/docker/containers`

it should have a matching log file in containers folder, for example if your deployment start with name `payments`, we can capture log of that particular service by providing

```
path /var/log/containers/payments*.log
```

in

```
<source>
  ....
  path /var/log/containers/payments*.log
  ....
</source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement separation on a file level. Instead, use `kubernetes_metadata` fluentd filter, which enriches every log record with the pod related metadata.

Example configuration: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/e8cb994ae938be784a55dfada297a7f4192a411c/docker-image/v1.10/debian-papertrail/conf/kubernetes.conf#L191-L201

Example input/output: https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter/tree/84f66a8f9e06ab5b5211053fcce4cd8ab4bd74ba#example-inputoutput

Once you have this, there are a couple ways to filter out particular service:

- ship all logs to logging backend, e.g. elasticsearch, and filter there by metadata.
- use the filter `@type grep` to grep by metadata in fluentd, and ship only your service.
- use the filter `@type rewrite_tag_filter` to transform metadata into the tag, and then use fluentd match rules to separate the logs.

Comment: May I know why implementing separation on a file level is discouraged? It seems easier.

Comment: You are re-implementing the knowledge about the CRI log file organization in this case, which is already done in many upstream log collectors

Comment: You have a much much better interface to work with - a full cluster log stream enriched with all the metadata, so why not use it